# In PLSQL, how do you iteratively update a field of a very large table?

Tags: database, plsql, oracle11g

I have a PLSQL table with 30 million rows and I want to update a field for all rows.

I tried a loop (batching up the update into 100000 row intervals) but I can't use

```
update tableA set columnA=1 where rownum between lower and upper
```

where the loop moves through new upper and lower values until the rowcount is exhausted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to do the update iteratively?  Why don't you want to do a simple `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE tableA
   SET columnA = 1
```

That't the most efficient way to update a large number of rows.  It also generates the least amount of `REDO` and `UNDO`.

Comment: a simple update like this throws an error with 30 million rows

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - What error?  Why do you believe that breaking the `UPDATE` into multiple parts will not generate that same error?

Comment: unable to extend index "something" by 1024

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn - That error is not going to go away if you do an incremental update.  Depending on the Oracle error number and the specific text of the error message, it probably implies that whatever tablespace the specified index is in doesn't have enough free space to grow the index to accomodate the `UPDATE`.